# Should I restrain myself from downvoting answers on question where I have answered as well

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

Sometimes I face this ethical dilemma when I want to downvote a bad answer but I'm not sure whether I should.

On the one hand, there's the chance of a conflict of interest: I have answered the question as well and deep down I want to win the green checkmark ;)

On the other hand, the answer is objectively bad or counterproductive.

Should I restrain from voting and let others in the community take care of the bad answer?

Answer (score 12):

If it is a bad answer and you would have downvoted had you not also answered, then by all means downvote. But, if you're downvoting bad answers you ***should upvote good answers too***.

If you vote—vote fairly and objectively. If you do feel more comfortable not voting on competing answers then that is perfectly reasonable too—there is no obligation to vote.